# how to compare multiple arrays for higher value based on one specific key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple arrays. I want to compare these arrays key values with one another and output only one array which has the higher value than others. Here is my array

```
array(4) { ["type"]=> string(6) "Person" ["relevance"]=> string(8) "0.645481" ["count"]=> string(1) "1" ["text"]=> string(15) "RAJESH NELATURI" }
array(4) { ["type"]=> string(6) "Person" ["relevance"]=> string(8) "0.567918" ["count"]=> string(1) "2" ["text"]=> string(11) "Layoutlands" } 
array(4) { ["type"]=> string(6) "Person" ["relevance"]=> string(8) "0.546824" ["count"]=> string(1) "1" ["text"]=> string(9) "N. Rajesh" }
```

I want to compare the key "relevance" and filter the array which has higher relevance value. In this case The first array which has the value "0.645481" and print the arrays `key[text]`. Here it should print **RAJESH NELATURI**

Comment: So what have you tried ?

Comment: What is "key value"?

Comment: by key value i mean value of the array key, ex. "Person" is the value of the key [type]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
$higher = array('relevance' => 0);
foreach($myArray as $key) {
  if($key['relevance'] > $higher['relevance']){
      $higher = $key;    
  }
}
```

At the end, `$higher` will have the biggest `relevance` and is equal to :

```
$higher = array(4) { ["type"]=> string(6) "Person" ["relevance"]=> string(8) "0.645481" ["count"]=> string(1) "1" ["text"]=> string(15) "RAJESH NELATURI" }
```

now you can print the higher `text` :

```
echo  $higher['text'];
```

**UPDATE:**

But it seems all 'relevance' values in your array are string, So they can not be compared with each other! you have to change them to `float`,

Try to produce this array in another way to have `float` values,

If you can't, Try this code instead :

```
$higher = array('relevance' => 0);
foreach($myArray as $key) {
  if((float)$key['relevance'] > (float)$higher['relevance']){
      $higher = $key;    
  }
}
```

this code changes string to float before compare.

Comment: I tried your solution , but it gives me the warning illegal string asset at this line `if ($output['relevance'] > $higher_rel['relevance']) {` and `echo  $higher['text'];`

Comment: @NaveenKumar It's because `$myArray['relavance']` is a string and can not  be compared with int. I will update the answer

Comment: I tried to do what you said. But still throws the error

Comment: let me test it myself

Comment: it's weird! my code is working. here is the code :  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e23a191b750eebb9e8b0d65d46dff76c22b2e1a

Comment: check this tried the same it throws me error [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01609a24e74447c5f1d7c5a69e0e91b5b97c73d2]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131948/discussion-between-ahmad-mobaraki-and-naveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the arrays in a replace-if-higher basis.

```
$currentMax = PHP_INT_MIN; // it is impossible for any entries to be smaller than this value

foreach($arrays as $array){
    $keyValue = $array["relevance"]; // not exactly sure what you mean by "key value"
    if($keyValue > $currentMax){
        $currentMax = $keyValue;
        $currentName = $array["text"]'
    }
}
```

`$currentName` should be set as lonig as `$arrays` is not empty and the `$keyValue` of any entries is greater than `PHP_INT_MIN`.

Comment: by key value i mean value of the array key, ex. "Person" is the value of the key [type]

Answer (score 0):

find the relevance with max value, and the index. Here is the code, hope it helps.

```
$relevances = array_column($array, 'relevance');
$values = array_values($relevances);
$map = array_combine($values, array_keys($$relevances));
echo $array[$map[max($values)]]['text'];
```